# Implementing correlated random walk and a levy walk in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

Does anyone have any sample code or know how to implement a correlated random walk or a levy walk in netlogo?

*** I need it to do spatially explicit modeling of animal movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
globals [alpha minstep]

to setup
  ca
  set alpha 1.5 set minstep 0.2 ;or whatever
  crt 1 [pen-down]
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    set heading random-float 360
    fd minstep * (random-float 1) ^ (-1 / alpha)
  ]
end
```

**Edit:**

The following is perhaps the simplest way to get a correlated angle.

```
to-report randomAngleTriangular [
  #maxAngle  ;(number) angle in degrees
  ]
  let _maxAngle abs #maxAngle
  if (_maxAngle > 180) [
    set _maxAngle 180
  ]
  report (2 * randomStandardTriangular - 1) * _maxAngle
end

to-report randomStandardTriangular
  report (random-float 1 + (1 - random-float 1)) / 2
end
```

For a correlated random walk, just change `heading` by turning (left or right) by the reported angle.

Comment: I should have mentioned: also see the Mushroom Hunt model in the Railsback and Grimm textbook.  (Not a Levy flight, but related to your question.)

Comment: Thank you Alan, this was very helpful, for the levy walk ... I have good direction on how to proceed with this now ... how about a correlated random walk? Any ideas on how to implement that?

Comment: Hello Alan or anyone else who can possible help me with this: I have been able to implement a levy walk and correlated random walk in netlogo using the code below (with sliders and buttons for increased functionality). However, the correlated random walk is not functioning accordingly ...

Comment: @nigus21 It is both impossible to read and considered bad etiquette to use comments to ask new questions.  Instead, as a new question.  Also, be sure to read
https://www.google.com/search?q=stackexchange+how+to+accept+an+answer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Thank you for the advice, my apologies for the unclear presentation of my questions as comments. I will ask the subsequent questions separately. Thanks for your answers to my initial questions. I am fairly new to stack exchange so I am still getting used to the etiquette here. I do need some clarification in regards to executing the code ... I shall be asking for clarification in a separate question!